# How to insert value into primary key column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
insert into Student 
values('1', 'joedio', 'newyark', GETDATE())
```

I get this error message when trying to run this SQL:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Student' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: Error says every thing

Comment: @Sandip-FrontendDeveloper Obviously not, or else the question would not have been asked.

Answer (score 25):

If you wants to insert primary key by query even it is auto increment then you have to set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` as below, it will allow you to insert unique value by query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Tablename] ON;
```

Your query will be now:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON;

INSERT INTO Student VALUES('1','joedio','newyark',GETDATE());

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student OFF;
```

If you wants that SQL manage it self then default it set to `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` and Auto increment is set, means on every insert the new value is assigned to that PK column.

**Better to execute** with default setting `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student OFF` because by manual inset possibility to insert duplicate value and it will throw an error.

Comment: check your column `IDENTITY_INSERT` property

Comment: I found I had to specify the column names as well to get this to work using a select statement. i.e. INSERT INTO Student (column1, coulumn2.......columnN) SELECT value1, value2...... valueN FROM Table

as opposed to INSERT INTO Students SELECT.........

Answer (score 13):

If your table has `Identity Column`, then you have to mention all the other columns while inserting.

Just it is for sample:

```
INSERT INTO Student (ID, Name, State, Date) VALUES('1','joedio','newyark',GETDATE())
```

If the First column is Identity, then skip the value while inserting:

```
INSERT INTO Student (Name, State, Date) VALUES('joedio','newyark',GETDATE())
```

And If you want to Insert Values into an Identity Column in `SQL Server`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable ON

INSERT INTO Student (ID, Name, State, Date) VALUES('1','joedio','newyark',GETDATE())

SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable OFF
```

And also refer the link [How to Insert Values into an Identity Column in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-insert-values-into-an-identity-column-in-sql-server) for More information.

Comment: i just want to insert first column that is identity column value manually . what to do?

Answer (score 6):

**TRY THIS:** If you really want to insert a value into the `IDENTITY` column, then you must enable this for the table first

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Tablename] ON;
INSERT INTO [Tablename]..........
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Tablename] OFF;
```

Otherwise, just get rid of the error by excluding the first value from the `values`

```
INSERT INTO Student --No need to add column definition if you are inserting rest of all
VALUES('joedio', 'newyark', GETDATE()) --Error Free
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to clear out this concept by taking a look at it.

[IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)

And after mentioning the primary key as identity, you need not to pass an argument for its value. Its value will be auto incremented.

Answer (score 1):

1. In sql server when ID column is Auto Incremental and you are passing ID

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID = 1)
    THEN

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON;

```
INSERT INTO Student (ID, Name, State, Date) VALUES('1','joedio','newyark',GETDATE())
```

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student OFF;

```
END
```

2.In sql server when ID column is Auto Incremental and you are not passing ID

```
INSERT INTO Student (Name, State, Date) VALUES('joedio','newyark',GETDATE())
```

3.In My sql use can use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Student (ID, Name, State, Date) VALUES('1','joedio','newyark',GETDATE());
```

OR

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Student (Name, State, Date) VALUES('joedio','newyark',GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

IDENTITY_INSERT allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a table.
Use this query and set IDENTITY_INSERT on the table 'on'

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON
```

Note: At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON;

INSERT INTO Student (RegNo, Name, Address, CreatedTime) VALUES('2','calibio','newyark',GETDATE());

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student OFF;
```